# Html.EditorFor perdendo valor ao reiniciar a página

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

estou iniciando meu html.editorfor com "0,00" assim:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Preco, new { htmlAttributes = new { @Value = "0,00"} })
```

Porém quando o usuário recebe alguma mensagem de validação (ModelState.IsValid=false) o editorfor acaba perdendo o valor e volta para "0,00" . A pergunta é: Teria como eu iniciar o editorfor com "0,00" e depois que o usuário digitar o novo valor eu mantê-lo mesmo se o ModelState.IsValid retornar false?

Comment: E se você passar ao invés de passar {Value = "0,00"}, passar por {Value = model.Preco.ToString("0,00")}, ai a primeira vez é só iniciar o model (não  passar null) e depois que testar o ModelState (no httpPost) passar o mesmo model que recebeu por parâmetro de volta a view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há várias formas de conseguir isso.
Talvez a mais simples seja:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Preco, new { htmlAttributes = new { Value = Model != null? Model.Preco.ToString("0.00") : "0.00" }})
```

Comment: Valeu Daniel, deu certo!